# Reliable method for checking that an online file exists

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have the following code which checks that a file exists on a website. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work it invokes EIdHTTPProtocolException and returns 0 even though the file is present on the server. Does anyone have an idea for why it doesn't always work? It seems more likely to work if I'm debugging the code, so I wonder if it has to do with timing?

This is an FMX application running on Windows and I'm using Delphi 10.4.

Note that I have changed the link to a fake one for posting here so obviously the code below will always return 0 if you try it.

```
uses IdHTTP, IdStack;

function CheckFileOnlineExists(const OnlineFile: string; var Size: Int64): Byte;
var
 IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Result := 0; // File not found
  IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  try
    IdHttp.Head(OnlineFile);
    Size := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength;
    if Size > 0 then Result := 2; // File found
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do ;
    on E: EIdSocketError do Result := 1; // No internet
  end;
finally
  IdHttp.Free;
end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  LSize : Int64;
  LRes : Byte;
begin
  // Check if online file exists
  LRes := CheckFileOnlineExists('http://websiteurl.com/file_test.png', LSize);
  if (LRes <> 2) or (LSize <> 5497) then begin
    if LRes = 0 then
      Caption := 'Website check file not found. This app will close'
    else
      Caption := 'Internet connection is needed to run this application';
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I suggest you capture traffic (For example using WireShark) and see when it doesn't work what is wrong at the HTTP protocol at least. Maybe the server abandon the connection before the file is completely sent?

Comment: @fpiette It is a HEAD request, it does not send the file, just some information about it. It is very short communication so it not expected to fail (often).

Comment: Maybe I should use a while loop to keep checking until it succeeds or reaches a max count of something like 10.

Comment: If the file does not exist, the server should send you a 404, it's valid for a file to exist with zero size.  As for why you have a protocol error, I recommend you follow @fpiette's advice and check the actual http conversation to see what's happening.

Comment: Just like @RobLambden wrote: you also need to check the [HTTP status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes): 200 is a strong indicator, but 404 and 410 too. You can't be even sure if 301 and 307 are automatically followed to the new URI, let alone what happens if none is given with that status. The content length is also **not** automatically the one of the "file" you expect - it could also be the size of a customized 404 page.

Comment: @AmigoJack - yes, the questions checks for the length of the body of the response which in many cases will be 0, and of course has no bearing at all on the size of the file.

Comment: There are 3 possible outcomes when checking if a file exists across the internet or in general : yes, no and could not determine. You need to more closely examine the responses and errors and for each decide which outcome it is.

Comment: Thanks to all. Note that the file will be on my website, so I have complete control over it. The idea is that I'm releasing an alpha version of my software but I want to be able to disable it remotely at some point in the future. My idea for doing that was to get it to check a file on my website. At some point in the future I would delete that file and disable the software for everyone who may have got their hands on it. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

By default, `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised when `TIdHTTP` receives an error reply from the HTTP server.  The exception's `ErrorCode` property will contain the server's numeric error code.  In this case, `404` for `not found`.  You should be handling that case specifically.

Also, as others stated in comments, a remote file can exist and be 0 bytes in size.  So you should not be using the `ContentLength` as an indication of existence.  If `TIdHTTP.Head()` exits without reporting an error, the file exists, period.

Try this instead:

```pascal
function CheckFileOnlineExists(const OnlineFile: string; var Size: Int64): Byte;
var
  IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      // TODO: set IdHttp.Request.Accept to tell the server which
      // type of file you will accept and nothing else...
      IdHttp.Head(OnlineFile);
      // TODO: verify the Response.ContentType before assuming success,
      // in case the server sends a 200 OK reply containing an HTML
      // login form or error webpage...
      Size := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength;
      Result := 2; // File found
    finally
      IdHttp.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
      Result := iif(E.ErrorCode = 404, 0, 3); // 0: File not found; 3: HTTP error
    end;
    on E: EIdSocketError do Result := 1; // No internet
    on E: Exception do Result := 4; // Unknown error
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LSize : Int64;
  LRes : Byte;
begin
  // Check if online file exists
  LRes := CheckFileOnlineExists('http://websiteurl.com/file_test.png', LSize);
  case LRes of
    0: begin
      Caption := 'Website file not found. This app will close';
    end;
    1: begin
      Caption := 'Internet connection is needed to run this application';
    end;
    2: begin
      if LSize = 5497 then Exit;
      Caption := 'File is not the expected size. This app will close';
    end;
    3: begin
      Caption := 'Website file error. This app will close';
    end;
  else
    begin
      Caption := 'Unknown error. This app will close';
    end;
  end;
  Close;
end;
```

That being said, you can avoid the overhead of `EIdHTTPProtocolException` being raised on commonly-handled errors by either:

- enabling the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property:

```pascal
function CheckFileOnlineExists(const OnlineFile: string; var Size: Int64): Byte;
var
 IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
      // TODO: see above...
      IdHttp.Head(OnlineFile);
      if (IdHttp.ResponseCode div 100) = 2 then
      begin
        // TODO: see above...
        Size := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength;
        Result := 2; // File found
      end
      else if IdHttp.ResponseCode = 404 then
      begin
        Result := 0; // File not found
      end
      else begin
        Result := 3; // HTTP error
      end;
    finally
      IdHttp.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdSocketError do Result := 1; // No internet
    on E: Exception do Result := 4; // Unknown error
  end;
end;
```

- passing `404` (and any other error code you are interested in) to the `AIgnoreReplies` parameter of `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()`:

```pascal
type
  TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
  end;

function CheckFileOnlineExists(const OnlineFile: string; var Size: Int64): Byte;
var
 IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      // TODO: see above ...
      TIdHTTPAccess(IdHttp).DoRequest('HEAD', OnlineFile, nil, nil, [404]);
      Result := IdHttp.ResponseCode <> 404;
      if Result then
      begin
        // TODO: see above ...
        Size := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength;
      end;
    finally
      IdHttp.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
      Result := 3; // some other HTTP error
    end;
    on E: EIdSocketError do Result := 1; // No internet
    on E: Exception do Result := 4; // Unknown error
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the file is on my web server and is known to have non zero size.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  Checking the size for 0 is not the right way to check if the file exists.  The HTTP response codes will tell you that instead. Your `OnActivate` handler is validating the size separately if the file exists, let it do its job, don't do that validation inside of `CheckFileOnlineExists()` itself. That is not what `OnActivate` is asking `CheckFileOnlineExists()` for.

Comment: The `else` in a `case` section is already beginning a block (just like a `finally` or `except` in a `try` section) and doesn't need a redundant `begin ... end` for multiple expressions.

Comment: @AmigoJack I'm aware of that, but I've never liked how omitting the `begin..end` makes the code look, so I prefer to use the `begin..end` explictly.